# Running powershell from Perl and getting a return value

Tags: perl, powershell

I am running a Perl script that calls a powershell script. Is there a way for me to get a return value from this? I've tried something similar to

```
my @output = "powershell.exe powershellscript.ps1;
foreach(@output)
{
   print $_;
}
```

and I get nothing out of it. Do I need to add something to the powershell script to push the return values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with backsticks,

```
my @output = `powershell.exe powershellscript.ps1`;
foreach (@output)
{
   print $_;
}
```

Comment: I went witht his one and it worked great. Thanks everyone for the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks to run and collect the output:

```
my @output = ` ...`
```

If you want the return code (status) too, do (by example):

```
perl -e '@output=`/bin/date`;print $?>>8,"\n";print "@output"'
```

See [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for more information on interpreting the return code.

**ADDENDUM**

In lieu of backticks, which can sometimes be annoying to read, you can use `qx(STRING)` as described in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).  This is analogous to collecting process output in shell scripts where, in POSIX-compliant shells, capture may be done with the archaic backticks, or more readably, with `OUTPUT=$(/bin/date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a named pipe:

```
open(PWRSHELL, "/path/to/powershell.exe powershellscript.ps1 |") or die "can't open powershell: $!";
while (<PWRSHELL>) {
    # do something
}
close(PWRSHELL) or warn "can't close powershell: $!";
```